# is this '' cause and effect sentence ''?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence a cause and effect sentence? Why ?

> They have the advantage of providing simultaneous hemostasis, which helps prevent debridement of normal tissue.

Comment: What is a "cause and effect sentence"? Where did you come across it? Does that source define it? It's not a phrase I've ever heard, and it occurs only once in the iWeb corpus of 14 billion words.